# Directory or File contain space error in Shell Script

Tags: macos, cocoa, shell

I need to encrypt my resource image files in my project so I used [NK-Encrypter](https://github.com/DiamondTechIT/NK-Encrypter/blob/master/webViewOnLoad/EncryptedFileURLProtocol.m) and I write run script like this

```
DIRNAME=ImageFiles/Images
        RESOURCES=Resources
        ENC_KEY="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456"

        INDIR=$PROJECT_DIR/$DIRNAME
        OUTDIR=$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/$RESOURCES/$DIRNAME

        if [ ! -d "$OUTDIR" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$OUTDIR"
        fi

     for file in $`find $INDIR -type f`
        do
        echo "Encrypting $file"
        "$PROJECT_DIR/crypt" -e -k $ENC_KEY -i "$file" -o "$OUTDIR/`basename "$(dirname ${file})"`/`basename "$file"`"
        done
```

I have faced a problem when the directory or file contain space it shows error `Shell Script Invocation Error Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1` how can I fix this.

Comment: `for file in $`find $INDIR -type f` doesn't look well. You might want to use `for file in $(find $INDIR -type f)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic; don't use for .. in, use

```
find "$INDIR" -type f | while read file; do
  echo "Encrypting $file"
  "$PROJECT_DIR/crypt" -e -k $ENC_KEY -i "$file" -o "$OUTDIR/`basename "$(dirname ${file})"`/`basename "$file"`"
done
```